# Time.timeScale not working for Unity.Physics package (DOTS)

Tags: unity-game-engine, entity-component-system, unity-dots

if I set Time.timeScale = 0; nothing changes, if set Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0; my physical objects begin to behave strangely, but do not stop completely.
Maybe someone knows how to change timeScale for DOTS Physics

Comment: Someone in a related thread mentions they can fully pause the game -- if that's what you need, instead of just slowing it down -- by "switching the StepPhysicsWorld system off". Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Alas, I need to slow down, just like Time.timeScale in old unity physics

Answer (score 0):

In `Unity.Physics\ECS\Base\Systems\StepPhysicsWorld.cs` inside the `OnUpdate()` function modify the timeStep value with your scalar so it would look something like this :

```cs
float timeStep = Time.DeltaTime * PhysicsSettings.TimeScale;

// Schedule the simulation jobs
Simulation.ScheduleStepJobs(new SimulationStepInput()
{
   World = m_BuildPhysicsWorldSystem.PhysicsWorld,
   TimeStep = timeStep,
   Gravity = stepComponent.Gravity,
   SynchronizeCollisionWorld = stepComponent.SynchronizeCollisionWorld > 0,
   NumSolverIterations = stepComponent.SolverIterationCount,
   SolverStabilizationHeuristicSettings = stepComponent.SolverStabilizationHeuristicSettings

}, m_Callbacks, handle, stepComponent.MultiThreaded > 0);
```

Where `PhysicsSettings` is my class for storing dots physics global variables.